# Typescript can not find node core modules

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to write a class with TypeScript and therefore I'd like to import some native node modules which fails because of

> [ts] Can not find module 'net'.

The same issue happens for other native node modules. However it does work for bluebird for example. (See Screenshot).

[image]

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "types": ["node"]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

**My question:**

Why does it not recognize native modules like 'net' ?

Edit: This error is thrown when executing the build task: error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'

Comment: Have you installed `@types/node`?

Comment: @cartant I didn't know about it, after installing the build error is gone, but it still can't find the module according to intellisense

Comment: A VsCode restart fixed it after installing @types/node

Comment: Maybe restart the IDE to see if intellisense comes good. Unrelated, but you usually only need to specify `types` in the `tsconfig.json` to specifically exclude unlisted types. Unless you want to ignore some types, you might want to remove that setting entirely.